# mysql subquery where and group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, where-clause

I'm learning mysql  manual:
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html
and i'm confused with the "where.s1.article = s2.article' part, what is this mean?

```
Task: For each article, find the dealer or dealers with the most expensive price.

+---------+--------+-------+
| article | dealer | price |
+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |
|    0003 | B      |  1.45 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0003 | D      |  1.25 |
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |
+---------+--------+-------+


SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM   shop s1
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
              FROM shop s2
              WHERE s1.article = s2.article);

+---------+--------+-------+
| article | dealer | price |
+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

I'm trying to write the similar code:

```
SELECT sex, name, birthday
From   user
Where  birthday=(SELECT MAX(birthday)
              FROM user
              group by sex);
```

But mine outputs the error: subquery return more than 1 row, why?

Comment: I'm not sure, I might be wrong, but i think this is because `subquery returns more than 1 row`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The original query is called a *correlated subquery*. The `WHERE` clause in the subquery restricts the maximum found to just the article that matches the row being processed by the outer query.

In your query, you don't have a `WHERE` clause, so it processes everything in the table. It then returns results grouped by sex. I assume there are two sexes in your table, so it returns one row with the maximum for men, and another row containing the maximum for women. But `WHERE price = (<subquery>)` requires the subquery to return just a single result, because `=` can only be used with single values.

You can use `IN` instead of `=` to match against multiple returned values. This probably isn't what you want, but you haven't described what you want your query to do so it's hard to tell.

To get the youngest person of each sex, you can write a correlated subquery, like the one in the manual:

```
select sex, name, birthday
from user u1
where birthday = (select max(birthday)
                  from user u2
                  where u1.sex = u2.sex)
```

or you can use a join with a grouped subquery:

```
select u1.sex, name, u1.birthday
from user u1
join (select sex, max(birthday) maxbirthday
      from user
      group by sex) u2
on u1.sex = u2.sex and birthday = maxbirthday
```

Comment: I updated my code, I just pasted the wrong one, it maybe clear to anyone who see this post.

Comment: It's still the same problem. The subquery returns two birthdays, one for men, another for women. But `=` requires just one thing to compare with. If you want to correlate, you need to use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: yes, after reading your reply, I used 'in' instead of '=' and problem solved.

Comment: Are you sure it does what you want? It will show men with the same birthday as the latest women's birthday, and vice versa.

Comment: Oh, if a man and a women has the same birthday it may cause the problem, so I have to consider the where clause.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. But you didn't define what you wanted the query to return, so it was hard for me to contradict you.

Comment: I would like to return the youngest person of each sex, maybe I have to write the same codes as the example in the manual.

Comment: See the queries I added to the answer.

Comment: This is my understanding: For example, a person named Blake, his sex is male, according to your first code, u1.sex = u2.sex, u2.sex is male, then the computer calculate the max(birthday) of male group, if Blake's birthday = max(birthday), bingo! The computer outputs the result which means blake's birthday is youngest. English is not my main language, hope you can understand me.